# ORM/Hibernate Pattern: Class Foo has many Bars, with one of those Bars being the default

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'll try to keep this as simple as possible.  I think it's a little more ORM related than strictly Hibernate, but since I'm developing using Hibernate that's where I hit the problem and need the solution.  However if this other ORM frameworks don't have this problem then I'd like to know.

**Attempted pattern: Class Foo has many Bars, with one of those Bars being the default.**
My implementation is that the Bar table has a foo_id (onetomany), and the Foo table has a bar_id (representing a single bar that is the default.  Hibernate seems completely cool with this when initializing, but when I try retrieve a list of object Foo it throws up with a "key is null" assertion error and disparages my session mgmt. (Oddly it is able to get one of the foos just fine.)

I can imagine issues that ORM tools like hibernate might have with getting a set of something and then getting one of the same thing in the entity.  So how would I do this?  I can always set a flag in Bar that it is the default, but imagine if I had a large number of Bar objects and then I changed the default; I would have to update all those rows.  That seems like a poor solution to me.  Any ideas on the right way to make this work?  I know you ORM experts probably have 2 or n solutions to this off the cuff.

Pseudo code that hopefully clarifies what I'm trying to get at below.

```
@Table(name="foo")
public class Foo  {

  protected Collection<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
  protected Bar defaultBar = null;
  .
  .
  .

  @OneToMany (mappedBy="foo")
  public Bar getBars() {
     return bars;
  }

  public void setBars(Collection<Bar> bars) {
    this.bars = bars;
  }

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="default_bar_id")
  public void setDefaultBar(Bar defaultBar) {
    this.defaultBar = defaultBar;
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isnt a  nice way to do it.. Like you said one of the ways could be to introduce a column in bar to identify default but since you are suggesting it can change and you dont want to update the other rows what you can do is probably set some kind of property thats comparable and thus you can determine which is the latest default. I am thinking something like DateTimeOffset.. and thus the default will be the one with the highest offset which you update as and when you wish.

The other solution that I can think of would be to introduce another object/table to hold this default Bar. something like this

```
public Class DefaultBar
{
public Bar DefaultBar;
}
```

and the mapping would be from Foo to DefaultBar which you can update.